# MVC :The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter Item'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I have one form Called Visitors Form. In that i have  one dropdown called Purpose of Visit. If I select the Purpose of Visit as "**Trial** " it open one pop up window.

In pop-up Window i have two fields called Item and Quantity

Item is Dropdown and Quantity is textbox.which i shown in the below image

[image: Multiple item]

In Pop window i have two fields called Item and Quantity and near to this i have one add button to add multiple items. If i select Item and quantity and click add buttons means it will add the item in list. Like this i can add multiple item .

Now my issue is if i select the Item and quantity it didnt add the item in the list that is in the table which is mention in the below image

[image: Empty Table]

**My Model(VisitorsViewMode)**

```
   public string POVisit { get; set; }
   public Nullable<System.Guid> ItemID { get; set; } 
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public int SNO { get; set; }
   public string ItemText { get; set; }
```

**My Controller Code**

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Session["itemList"] = null;
        ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "DisplayName");
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult AddMultipleItems(int sNo, Guid itemId, string itemText, int quanitty)
    {
        var itemModelListList = new List<VisitorsViewModel>();
        if (sNo > 0)
        {
            if (Session["itemList"] != null)
            {
                var savedItemListes = Session["itemList"] as List<VisitorsViewModel>;
                var saveditem = savedItemListes.FirstOrDefault(sd => sd.SNO == sNo);
                if (saveditem != null)
                {
                    saveditem.ItemText = itemText;
                    saveditem.ItemID = itemId;
                    saveditem.Quantity = quanitty;
                }
                itemModelListList = savedItemListes;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["itemList"] != null)
            {
                var savedItemListes = Session["itemList"] as List<VisitorsViewModel>;
                if (savedItemListes != null && savedItemListes.Count > 0)
                    sNo = savedItemListes.Max(m => m.SNO) + 1;
                else
                    sNo = 1;
                itemModelListList = savedItemListes;
            }
            else
                sNo = sNo + 1;

            var orderformmodel = new VisitorsViewModel();
            orderformmodel.SNO = sNo;
            orderformmodel.ItemText = itemText;
            orderformmodel.ItemID = itemId;
            orderformmodel.Quantity = quanitty;
            itemModelListList.Add(orderformmodel);
            Session["itemList"] = itemModelListList;

        }
        return Json(itemModelListList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My View**

```
  @model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.VisitorsViewModel
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <fieldset> 

    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
   @Html.Label("Purpose of Visit", new { @class = "control-label", styles = "font-family: Arial;" })
   @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
    </div>
   </div>

  <div id="Trial-dialog-modal" title="Trial Form" style="display:none">
  <div class="box-body">
  <div>Customer Name</div>
  <div id="customername"></div>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerID, new { id = "customerid" })

   @Html.Label("Item")
   @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })

   @Html.Label("Quantity")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddItems" onclick="AddItems(0);">Add Items</a>


   <div class="box-body table-responsive" style="background-color: aliceblue; display: none;" id="divItemList">
   <table id="ItemTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="color: #1a1ae9">S.No</th>
    <th style="color: #1a1ae9"> Item Name</th>
    <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Quantity</th>
    <th style="color: #1a1ae9">Action</th>
      </tr>
        </thead>
           </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
   }
```

**Ajax Code**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
function AddItems(sNo) {
    debugger;
    if (validateQuantity()) {
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("AddMultipleItems", "VisitorsForm")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                sNo: 0,
                itemId: $("#ItemID").val(),
                itemText: $("#ItemID :selected").text(),
                quanitty: $("#Quantity").val(),
            },
            success: function (itemList) {
                debugger;
                $("#ItemTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                $("#hdnSno").val(0);
                if (itemList.length > 0) {
                    $.each(itemList, function (i, item) {
                        var items = '<tr> <td>' + item.SNO + '</td> <td>' + item.ItemText + '</td> <td>' + item.Quantity + '</td> <td><a href="#" id="dDonDel" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="DeleteDonation('
                                    + item.SNO + ');"></a></td></tr>';
                        $("#ItemTable").append(items);
                    });
                    clearitemsdetails();
                    $("#btnAdd").show();
                }
                else {
                    var items = '<tr><td colspan=6>No Data.</td></tr>';
                    $("#ItemTable").append(items);
                }
            }

        });
        $("#divItemList").attr("style", "display:block");
        $("#btnAdd").show();
    }
  }

     function clearitemsdetails() {
    $('#ItemID').val(''),
      $('#Quantity').val('')
  }

function validateQuantity() {
    var qty = $("#Quantity").val();
    if (qty == "" || qty == "0") {
        alert("Quantity cannot be blank, should be grater than 0.");
        $("#Quantity").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
    </script>
```

I checked the Error in Browser in shows some error which is mention in the below image

[image: Error]

I tried many ways to clear my issue but problem is not cleared.Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Advance thanks

Comment: Clearly the value of `$("#ItemID").val()` is `null` when you make your ajax call - debug your code!

Comment: @StephenMuecke in Ajax debug only i found this error . This error is in console only

Comment: @StephenMuecke it not hitting the controller as per url which is wrote in the controller

Comment: It wont if the value of `$("#ItemID").val()` is `null` (its throwing an exception). You need to ensure its not `null` (but why is you `ItemID` property nullable? - and if it can be, then make the parameter `Guid? itemID`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok lets i have a check and let you know

Comment: @StephenMuecke i changed the item property  from   public Nullable<Sysytem.Guid> ItemID { get; set; } to   public Guid ? ItemID { get; set; } but still same issue there

Comment: No! `Nullable<Sytem.Guid> ItemID` is identical to `Guid? ItemID` - its the parameter in the `AddMultipleItems()` controller method that you need to change be be nullable

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok now i change in that controller and let you know

Comment: @StephenMuecke I gave like this      public JsonResult AddMultipleItems(int sNo, Guid ? itemId  , string itemText, int quanitty)      its gave wrong output  which is mention in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAzrE.jpg  That is item not coming in the table

Comment: @StephenMuecke please tell how i correct that guid in controller in my question i post that controller code can you modify that and post here

Comment: Of course its not -your sending `null` to the method. And I have already asked you why you have `null` values in your dropdownlist (how do you expect me to know - I cant see your database and have no idea what your data is or why it contains `null` values - you need to debug your code)